# Register form android app using AWS cognito

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm building a register form for an android app. 
Now I want to use Amazon Cognito and DynamoDB, but I don't want users need to login using Facebook or Google (or any other similar service). They just need to be able to register and logging in using those credentials. How to do that?

Ow and I really don't want to configure my own server with database to store the users (I choose amazon for it's security and so I don't have to build my own infrastructure).

*The main reason I don't want to use facebook or google is because I want to give children, who don't have a facebook or google account, give the ability to register simply by entering an username and password.*

[image]

Now as far as I understand, I can use my own database with users to connect with cognito:

[image]

But I do not want to configure and secure my own web server with database where I store my users. The main reason I want to use Amazon in the first place is because it's secure and I don't have to build my own complete infrastructure.

So does anyone know or there is a better way to still use cognito and dynamodb, and giving users the ability to register without any of the existing services like Google or Facebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cognito's [Developer Authenticated Identities feature](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/devguide/identity/developer-authenticated-identities/) is designed to allow you to leverage an existing username/password store if you already have one. If you don't have a username/password store yet, I would recommend you look into using an OpenID Connect (OIDC) complaint identity provider (IdP). Since Cognito works with any OIDC-compliant IdP for authentication you could quickly and easily use this with Cognito. There are many OIDC-compliant IdPs out there and I cannot recommend any particular one, but, SecureAuth provides an OIDC-compliant Identity Provider and happen to have [just published a nice article explaining how to integrate with Cognito](https://www.secureauth.com/Resources/Blog/June-2015/Announcing-Full-Support-for-Integration-with-Amazo.aspx).

Comment: Looks great! Thanks you for your complete answer. Guess I'll try the demo

Comment: @ErikVandeVen How did this feature work out for your needs? I'd love to hear more about your experience with Amazon Cognito. Feel free to email me directly (see my profile).

Comment: To be honest, I haven't got the time to really look into it yet. Other projects have been given higher priority. As soon as I've got the chance to dive deeper into Cognito, I'll let you know :)

Answer (score 1):

For register, you don't need to authentication, which I mean you don't need Cognito. You can simply send register form to AWS Lambda function, then store in a DynamoDB table. For login/authentication, you need to implement your own identity provider incorporate with Cognito.

Comment: While the idea of using an external service such as in Scott Willeke's response is a great one, particularly if you need advanced feature such as provided by SecureAuth, for simpler requirements I think nowavewater's  approach is a bit simpler to manage because you don't then need separate accounts to manage your auth provider as well as AWS.  Having said that, I'd like to see a bit more detail on this, but it feels like a very good solution.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but if anyone is looking at a similar problem then you can directly use [Cognito user pool](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-identity-pools.html). This is introduced for the sole purpose of solving the problem you have stated (User management).

You can choose to have users sign in with an email address, phone number, username or preferred username plus their password or you can also use social identity providers for authentication and signing in or up for your app or website. Step by step details is provided in - https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-user-pools-for-amazon-cognito/. You also have lambda triggers for each authentication step in which you can invoke your own lambda and add stuff into Dynamo DB.

If you want to use AWS services you can use [Cognito identity pool](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-identity.html) and use Cognito User pool as its source to get temporary AWS credentials.